# Can't log in: Error occurred while sending a direct message or getting the response

Tags: authentication, openid

I'm unable to log into my account using my OpenID, `josh.gitlin.name` on either StackOverflow or Meta. The error message I receive after entering my OpenID on the login page and pressing "Login" is:

> Unable to log in with your OpenID
>   provider:
>
> Error occurred while sending a direct
>   message or getting the response

My alternate OpenID `hmblprogrammer.pip.verisignlabs.com` doesn't work either. Anything I can try? (And is there any way this question can be associated with my account even though I'm not logged in?)

Comment: Please try logging into http://test-id.org/RP/sreg.aspx and post the results of your attempt as an addendum to your question.

Comment: I am still unable to log in but I am back in my office now where my office computer was still logged in. I have now posted this question on meta where it belongs: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48006/cant-log-in-error-occurred-while-sending-a-direct-message-or-getting-the-respon